# python reverse_geocoder package behavior changes from shell to file

Tags: python

I installed the reverse_geocoder package (pip install reverse_geocoder) and tried to use it, but I encountered a behavior that I don't understand.

Executed within the shell, and entering these lines one by one:

```
import reverse_geocoder as rg
coordinates = (51.5214588,-0.1729636)
results = rg.search(coordinates)
print(results)
```

That gives me the following result:

```
Loading formatted geocoded file...  [OrderedDict([('lat', '51.51116'), ('lon', '-0.18426'), ('name', 'Bayswater'), ('admin1', 'England'), ('admin2', 'Greater London'), ('cc', 'GB')])]
```

Now, entering these lines in a .py file, and executing the file, I get a different result:

```
Loading formatted geocoded file...  [OrderedDict([('lat', '42.57952'), ('lon', '1.65362'), ('name', 'El Tarter'), ('admin1', 'Canillo'), ('admin2', ''), ('cc', 'AD')])]
```

I don't understand the behavior, can anyone help me understand ? The correct value is the first one.

EDIT: Once I get the second result (from executing the py file), then entering the lines one by one in the shell window is showing the same wrong value (same as executing the file); however, by restarting the shell and re-writing the lines one by one, I get the first result.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late, but adding `mode=1` gave me the correct results. `rg.search(coordinates,mode=1)` fixed my issues. The multithreading used on mode2 was probably causing the issues.